# How to find all virtio disks on machine?

Tags: linux, centos, disk-utility

So, `lsscsi` can list scsi devices, and `nvme list` can list nvme devices. What is the equivalent for virtio deivces?

Answer (score 3):

Use `lsblk` to list all block devices. This will find both virtio-blk devices (`vdX`) and virtio-scsi devices (`sdX`):

```
$ lsblk -d -o name,type,subsystems
NAME TYPE  SUBSYSTEMS
sda  disk  block:scsi:virtio:pci        (virtio-scsi)
vda  disk  block:virtio:pci             (virtio-blk)
```

In general, virtio devices (disk and non-disk) are PCI devices and will be seen in `lspci`.

Another method is to use udev:

```
udevadm trigger -v -n -s virtio | xargs -n 1 udevadm trigger -v -n -s block -b
```

Comment: my lsblk command does not have the subsystems column.

Comment: It's added by the `-o` option as shown in the example. Do you mean that the version in your distro is too old to have it?